# Hide a virtual folder in nginx

Tags: nginx, prestashop

I'm adjusting a brand new [thirty bees](http://thirtybees.com) installation (a prestashop fork) with several languages.

**Problem**: my domain is ".es" (like mydomain.es), and default language is Spanish. So, when a Spanish user load the page, in the url appears something like mydomain.es **/es/**.

I'm trying to "hide" the "/es/" alias (or virtual folder, whatever is called), so Spanish users can see mydomain.es/product-name instead of mydomain.es**/es/**product-name, but language still appears with other languages, like mydomain.es**/en/**product-name

So far, I've tried this:

```
location = /es/ {
        rewrite ^/es/(.*)$ /index.php last;
        }
```

And this:

```
rewrite ^/es/(.*)$ $1 last;
```

But nothing works, still appears /es/ folder.

Could anyone help me? 
**Thank you**!

PS: For detailed info, here's [my nginx vhost config](https://pastebin.com/NyLbDbcD)

Comment: Nginx is a Web server, it's not a web application. The difference is that a web server returns, caches, protects, etc. HTML pages and images prepared by a web application. So, if your HTML pages contain `<a href="/es...">`, Nginx will serve these HTML pages as is. What I am going to say is that the best idea would be to fix the issue in your web application.

Comment: `/es/` pages are virtual too, the real url is `domain.es/index.php?id_product=1&id_lang=1`, so language folder being a virtual rewrite, should be tweaked with my original question, I think..

Comment: Open your web site page, then look at its source. What links do you see? Next question: who generated such links in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /es/$1;
}
```